# How can I split a deck of 52 cards into 4 hands of 13 in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

For this project we are not able to use any collection classes. I have tried using a loop to create 4 arrays which each hold 13 cards, so they can later be sorted and presented to user. I can't work out how to populate 4 arrays with cards from the deck

My deal method:

```
public void deal() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Card[] hand = new Card[13];
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                hand[j] = deckOfCards[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create an array of 52 cards, shuffle it, create 4 arrays of 13 elements and pick cards from the top of the deck (the array of size 52).

Comment: I've already created the deck and have a shuffle method, I can't figure out the last part

Comment: you should reverse the loop that you have written, by the current logic, you are dealing 13 cards to one person, then going on to the next, instead : make `i` loop 13 times, and `j` loop 4 times only. This will be like giving one person one card, 13 seperate times.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have made a logical error. Lets make a dry run. The outer loop runs 4 times.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

Each time, a new array hand of type Card is created.

```
    Card[] hand = new Card[13];
```

Next we move to the j loop which runs 13 times for each value of i from 0-3,

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
```

Now inside the elements are stored in the array hand.

```
     //Logical error
     hand[j] = deckOfCards[j];
```

Now every time in the hand array, only the first 13 elements of deckOfCards are used.
You are not accessing elements from 13-51 of the array deckOfCards. To do that try changing this part of your code to this.

```
    hand[j] = deckOfCards[j + i*13];
```

This makes all the elements of deckOfCard to be accessed.

I hope I helped you.